# Cannot connect to redis using spring and lettuce

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I am struggling to find what could be wring here;  need help.
I am using spring-data-redis 2.4.1

```
RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration()
redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostname(hostname)
redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379)
redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword("password")
```

I then create `lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder` and specify `clientName`

I then use `lettuceClientConfiguration` and `redisStandaloneConfiguration` to create `ClientConnectionFactory`.

However, when we call `getConnection()` on the connection Factory, we get

```
WrongPass Invalid username-password pair
```

The same set of username-password works with Redis-CLI on cmd prompt.

Is there is something wrong in the way I am using in my java application?

Any pointer/hint towards solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the username set?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot configures LettuceConnectionFactory for you, you can specify the connection params on the *application.properties* file.

```
spring.redis.database=0
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.password=yourPassword
spring.redis.timeout=60000
```

If you wanna do it programmatically, set the `spring.redis.password` in *application.properties* and try this:

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("server", 6379));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had mistaken username for clientname set on LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder but username had to be specified on the redisstandaloneconfiguratuon.
This works for me; also please note acl was introduced only after lettuce 2.4.1 so any prior version will not work.

`redisStandaloneConfiguration.setUsername(connectionFactoryConfigs.getUserName());`